# Chrome does not return correct hour in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, time

First try is in IE 9 console:

```
new Date('2013-10-24T07:32:53') 
Thu Oct 24 07:32:53 UTC+0200 2013
```

returns as expected

Next try is in FireFox 24 console:

```
new Date('2013-10-24T07:32:53')
Date {Thu Oct 24 2013 07:32:53 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Standard Time)}
```

Then I go into Chrome 30 console:

```
new Date('2013-10-24T07:32:53')
Thu Oct 24 2013 09:32:53 GMT+0200 (Central Europe Daylight Time)
```

But the time is **09** here, it should be **07**.

Is this a bug in chrome or am I doing something wrong here?

I can't use any other format than this '2013-10-24T07:32:53' that I get by JSON from C#.
I need to get the hour of this timestamp, with the `getHours` I get the incorect value in Chrome.

**Solution:**

```
var inputHour = input.split('T')[1];
inputHour = inputHour.substring(0, 2);
```

Comment: It appears that Chrome expects you to pass it the time in GMT and it converts it to your local time.  The other browsers are interpreting the string you pass as local time.  I'm not sure which is correct, or if it's part of the spec.

Comment: @MikeEdwards—ECMA-262 ed 5 specifies only one string: [a version of ISO 9601 that is UTC](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15). If the timezone designator (Z) is omitted, you're back to implementation dependent (and IE 8 and lower won't correctly parse the ISO string anyway).

Comment: @Rumplin—put a "Z" on the end for ES5 compliant browsers, it will still fail in IE 8 and lower.

Comment: I did try to put the 'Z' at the end, and I still got the 09 hour.

Comment: It "works" for me in Chrome with or without the "Z" (v30), the string is assumed to be UTC. That is compliant with ES5: [The value of an absent time zone offset is “Z”](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its no bug. The implementation of date parse function differs across browsers & so does the format of the *dateString* accepted by it.

However this format seems to work same across ... [link](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_date.asp):

```
 new Date("October 13, 1975 11:13:00")
```

If possible, try and use

```
new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds)
```

for guaranteed results.

---

Regarding your format try parsing it yourself. Something like :

```
var str = '2013-10-24T07:32:53'.split("T");
var date = str[0].split("-");
var time = str[1].split(":");

var myDate = new Date(date[0], date[1]-1, date[2], time[0], time[1], time[2], 0);
```

---

Note *(Thanks to RobG for this)* : The Date constructor used above expects month as 0 - 11 & since October is 10 as per date String, the month has to be modified before passing it to the constructor.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: I can't use any other format. I get '2013-10-24T07:32:53' from a web service and need to get the hour from that JSON datetime format.

Comment: Why not split the string at `T` & construct the new date time string yourself then...

Comment: @Rumplin—the solution above assumes the string is **local time**, not UTC. Is that what you want? It will also set the month to the wrong value (it should have `--date[1]`).

Comment: the time that is in the string is the time that I need to read. No matter if UTC or GMT.

Answer (score 2):

See this thread:

[Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/javascript-date-parse)

It looks like the behavior of the parsing signature of the Date constructor is completely implementation dependent.

Comment: new Date(Date.parse('2013-10-24T07:32:53')); returns the same result as without 'parse'

Comment: @Rumplin—I think you missed the answer: `The Date.parse method is completely implementation dependent...I would recommend you to parse your date string manually`, which is very sound advice.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
var s = '2013-10-24T07:32:53';
```

in ES5 compliant browsers you could do:

```
var d = new Date(s + 'Z');
```

but for compatibility across all browsers in use, better to use (assuming date is UTC):

```
function dateFromString(s) {
  s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0],--s[1],s[2],s[3],s[4],s[5]));
}
```