# Different values with Date() in Chrome and IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome

In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Seenu/ryP3T/), the values for

```
     new Date(val[0]).getTime()
```

differ in Chrome and IE.
The chrome values appear to be proper, Is there a workaround to get the values correct in IE.

Code:

```
$(function () {
        var text="";
    $.each($.parseJSON("[{\"name\":\"critical\",\"data\":[[\"2013-10-01T00:00:00\",830],[\"2013-10-02T00:00:00\",257],[\"2013-10-03T00:00:00\",160],[\"2013-10-04T00:00:00\",200]]},{\"name\":\"normal\",\"data\":[[\"2013-10-01T00:00:00\",24],[\"2013-10-02T00:00:00\",20],[\"2013-10-03T00:00:00\",13],[\"2013-10-04T00:00:00\",30]]},{\"name\":\"ignore\",\"data\":[[\"2013-10-01T00:00:00\",1732],[\"2013-10-02T00:00:00\",1220],[\"2013-10-03T00:00:00\",1120],[\"2013-10-04T00:00:00\",1500]]}]"), function (key, value) {
            $.each(value.data, function (key, val) {
                text += "["+(new Date(val[0]).getTime()).toString()+","+ val[1].toString()+"]";
            });
        }
    );
    $("#container").html(text);
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome does not return correct hour in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19558004/chrome-does-not-return-correct-hour-in-javascript)

Comment: @mithataydogmus I checked too and saw different values

Comment: My bad, values after delimeter is same but before.. No. You right @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @mithataydogmus no problem. It wasn't the easiest job to see the differences.

Comment: Have you tried http://momentjs.com/ ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each browser is assuming a different timezone for [partial ISO formats](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) -- Chrome assumes they're in UTC while IE assumes they're local to the user.

```
console.log(new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00").getUTCHours());
// Chrome: 0
// IE 10:  5 (for US/Central)
```

If a timezone were included in the format, such as a `Z` for UTC, then they should parse the same:

```
console.log(new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00Z").getUTCHours());
// Chrome: 0
// IE 10:  0

console.log(new Date("2013-10-01T00:00:00-04:00").getUTCHours());
// Chrome: 4
// IE 10:  4
```

And, if needed, you can add it just before parsing:

```
new Date(val[0] + 'Z')
```