# How do I change chromes Date-parsing / Sorting to match ff/ie Dateparsing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, date, momentjs

So I encounter a very weird problem here and am out of ideas at the moment.

I've the following function to parse and sort a json object by  its property `RowDate`, 
containing datestrings with the following format: `"/Date(1389682861507+0100)/"`.

```
orderByDate: function (json) {
    debug('[DataCollection::orderByDate], json before ordering: ', json);

    _.each(json.LineDefinitions, function (line, i) {
        json.LineDefinitions[i].Artifacts.sort(function (a, b) { //Artifacts is an Array of json subobjects containing "RowDate"
            return MyApp.Utils.formatDate(a.RowDate) - MyApp.Utils.formatDate(b.RowDate);
        });
    });
    debug('[DataCollect::orderByDate], json after ordering: ', json);

    return json;
},
```

Here each `RowDate` contains a string like the one given above (different dates, though).

The `formatDate`-function looks like this:

```
MyApp.Utils.formatDate = function (date) {
    var ret;
    if (date instanceof Date) {
        ret = '/Date(' + date.getTime()
            + (date.getTimezoneOffset() <= 0 ? '+' : '-')
            + String(('0000' + ((date.getTimezoneOffset() / 60) * -100)).substr(-4)) + ')/';
    } else {
        ret = new Date(Number(String(date).replace(/(^.*\()|([+-].*$)/g, '')));
    }
    return ret;
};
```

for my problematic case, the programflow uses the `else`-condition.

Now it works out well in IE10 and 11(sic!) and Firefox 38.0.5, the resulting order is just right. But in chromes latest stable (you've heard right), v43.., i get the wrong ordering in my console.log, leading to unexpected behaviour later on in my app.

So I found this thread over here: [Different values with Date() in Chrome and IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567127/different-values-with-date-in-chrome-and-ie) (being in germany here, localtime might be different, so I think this might be the reason?!)

and tried to change the formatDate-else-line into the following ones, using momentjs (came to this project later on. first thing i changed was using momentjs everywhere...):

```
ret = moment.utc(date).toDate();
```

=> no effect, so I tried this from the momentjs-docs, too:

```
ret = moment(date, moment.ISO_8601).toDate();
```

but this doesn't seem to do the trick too. At the moment I am out of ideas and I hope you people here could help me out with my question: How do I change chromes Date-parsing to match ff/ie parsing? Or do I have a real big knot in my brain and some other thing went wrong here?

Would be great to hear from you!

**EDIT**
To make things clearer, I created this fiddle over here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/o3zh2kv4/8/

in IE and firefox, the output is:

`test1, test8, test2, test9, test3, test10, test4, test11, test5, test12, test6, test13, test7, test14,`

which is my desired output for further logic. but in chrome, i get the following:

`test8, test1, test9, test2, test10, test3, test4, test11, test5, test12, test6, test13, test7, test14,`

and I don't know why it is. Would be great to get some help here! I need chrome to change the order, too.

Comment: Can you describe the problem you are facing in more detail? You strip the date-string of the timezone, so that might be a problem.

Comment: @Rouby Thank you for your efforts so far, it seems it wasn't clear enough what I try at the moment. I added a fiddle which describes my problem better I think. Would be great to get further help! :)

Comment: I have removed my previous answer (as it does not solve your problem) and added a hopefully more helpful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is most likely caused by the fact, that different browser (engines) implement different algorithms for sorting.

The differences you experience are (at first glance) all focused on elements that have no difference (e.g. 0 returned from your sort-function) and thus have no deterministic sort-behavior described.

To fix this you would need to implement a custom sort-algorithm, or introduce more sort-criteria.

Comment: thanks for your answer. sadly, I don't have some more sort-criteria at this point in my code, so.... *shrugs* Seems like I have to create my own sortingalgorithm... i'll take a look at the sort-implementation of mozilla. *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, it's unspecified from 22.1.3.24 (https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-array.prototype.sort), "The elements of this array are sorted. The sort is not necessarily stable (that is, elements that compare equal do not necessarily remain in their original order). If comparefn is not undefined, it should be a function that accepts two arguments x and y and returns a negative value if x < y, zero if x = y, or a positive value if x > y."

In the current HEAD of V8 (and it's likely been like this for quite a while before I started hacking on it), Array.prototype.sort() always uses an unstable QuickSort, meaning there is no guarantee that equal values remain in the same order they were in before sorting.

Interestingly, the comment in the source indicates that we used to use a stable insertion sort on small arrays (<=22 elements), but the algorithm is not actually being used right now.

I recommend experimenting to see if you get unstable sorting behaviour with higher numbers of elements in spidermonkey or chakra, and by all means implement your own stable sort if it's needed.

Comment: thank you very much @chronicsalsa. I just filed an issue here: https://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4189#makechanges hoping they'll change it for the purpose of web compatibility :) Should be standardized (as everything) to have them in order I think (I just feel weird complaining about Chrome doing their very own thing, I always complain about the older IE-Browsers, but chrome...? :D )

Comment: It sounds like there are people who would support adding A.p.stableSort() to the spec similar to std::stable_sort() in c++11, in order to make sure stable sorts are available for those that need them. It's the sort of thing that could be easily polyfilled, too. So why not shoot an email to es-discuss about it and see if anyone is interested in writing up a proposal? --- If we had that, then we could continue gaming the benchmarks the way we are currently :D